# Schwarz Counter for a vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I am looking at a case where I would have a global static std::vector that I would need to guarantee is initialized (constructed) before certain static objects in an assortment of translation units.

When I look up how to handle this I come across two proposed solutions:

1. Have a static object in a global function that is used in place of a global static object.
2. Schwarz Counters

My concern with using a Schwarz counter is that the std::vector will be initialized twice.  From [this](http://www-d0.fnal.gov/KAI/doc/tutorials/static_initialization.html) link I get "A useful technique for ensuring that a global object is initialized only once and before its first use is to maintain a count of the number of translation units using it."

How does it work that the global is only initialized once?  By my reasoning it would be initialized twice.  Once in the normal course of static initialization and once when the first instance of the Schwarz counter is initialized.

On a related note, what would the initialization code look like in the Schwarz counter constructor?  I can only think of using a placement new.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5622574/179910

Answer (score 1):

I can only say how I've implemented it in the past: I design
a special "no-op" constructor, which does nothing, and use
placement new in the Schwartz counter.  Something like:

```
class ForUseAsStatic
{
public:
    enum MakeCtorNoop { makeCtorNoop };
    ForUseAsStatic();   //  normal ctor, called by Schwartz counter.
    ForUseAsStatic( MakeCtorNoop );
                        //  no-op constructor, used when
                        //  defining the variable.
};
```

Formally, this isn't guaranteed—the compiler is allowed to
set the memory to 0 again just before calling the constructor,
but I've never heard of a compiler which does.

It would also be possible to put some sort of flag in the class
itself, tested by the constructor.  This would only be valid for
static objects, of course (since it needs zero initialization in
order to work).

Another possible technique (which I've seen used in some
libraries) is to declare the memory for the objects in
assembler, or as a byte array if the compiler has some means of
forcing alignment.  Data names are not normally mangled, so this
will generally work, even if it is formally undefined behavior.
(For the standard library, of course, the library authors can
request extensions in the compiler to help them with the
problem.)

Finally: today, the singleton idiom, or something similar, is
generally preferred to such work-arounds.  It does mean that you
have to write `myobj().xxx`, rather than just `myobj.xxx`, but
this is not generally felt to be an issue.

Comment: Regarding the byte array strategy: in C++03 you can always declare more than the necessary size to be able to align on construction, in C++11 you have `std::aligned_storage<Size, Alignment>::type`.

Comment: This looks good for a custom type, but how would it work for an STL type, like std::vector?

Comment: @Graznarak It wouldn't work at all.  You could try the second possibility: declaring the raw memory, and counting on the fact that the compiler doesn't mangle type information into variable names, or you can wrap the STL type in a class which provides the same interface.  (This class would contain a pointer to the STL type, and use dynamic allocation for it, to be able to control exactly when it is constructed and destructed.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a right answer to the static initialisation problem the behaviour is undefined, and the selection of a solution depends on the specific circumstances.  It depends on:

- Your compiler and its implementation

  - most compilers offer guarantees within a single compilation unit
  - order can be determined by the linker and sometimes influenced with #pragma
  - initialisation can occur at any point before main begins executing.
  - Whether destructors will be called for global functions with static variables and when.
- The application architecture

  - Whether a .DLL is used, certain environments have reduced support for managing static construction/destruction in DLLs particularly when demand loaded.
  - Whether the application is threaded, this can have an effect on how global functions with static variables get called.

Possibly the best advice is to try to avoid this fiasco by designing your system in another way, although this might not be practical.  It does sound like your application does not need to take some of the concerns about portability into account and targets a specific environment with a specific compiler.

**#pragma / Compiler options**

One option you might not have considered is whether there is some compiler support for what you need.

For windows see:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104248

For g++:
Enable the `init-priority` and use `__attribute__ ((init_priority (n)))`.

**Getting Swartz counters to work**

What some examples omit is the object that is space is just reserved for the object being allocated that is appropriately aligned. This avoids one of the constructions you mention. For example in g++ gnu use:

```
typedef char fake_istream[sizeof(istream)] __attribute__ ((aligned(__alignof__(istream))))
...
fake_istream cin;
```

to allocate the space for the object.  All code outside that compilation unit will refer to this area as `extern istream cin` (via the headers) and is initialised with an in-place new. Some care should be taken to make sure that the *nifty* counter is thread-safe (atomic).

Answer (score 0):

You could use another level of indirection: have your global variable be a pointer to the vector (which will be zero-initialized), and have your counter `new` the vector and store the result in the pointer.

Comment: I would say that this is generally a good idea, but I tend to work in embedded systems and memory fragmentation and dynamic allocation is frowned upon unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: "There isn't a problem in programming you can't solve by just adding another level of indirection...accept removing a layer of indirection"